# Pronunciation of “œuf” and “œufs”

Tags: prononciation, pluriel

I heard the *œuf* in “un œuf” pronounced `/œf/`, but the *œufs* in “six œufs” pronounced `/ø/` (that is, without the `/f/` sound).  Is the plural always pronounced this way?  Is this just a special feature of the word *œuf*, or are there other words like it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> are there other words like it?

As far as I know, there isn't but one: bœuf(s).

> Is the plural always pronounced this way?

[Yes](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/b%C5%93ufs), it is (if you omit the liaison with the preceding word).

Comment: Is the plural always pronounced this way? No, it isn't actually: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/œufs ('*six œufs* /sizø/, but *une douzaine d'œufs* /...dœf/). Although this is currently changing in practice.

Comment: @Joce if I had to guess it's because _douzaine d'œufs, cent mille…_ would sound like _douzaine, deux cent mille…_. And like I said in my answer that's due to the liaison.

Answer (score 14):

That's indeed a very special feature. Usually, words are pronounced the same in their singular and plural forms. In rare cases the endings may change, but the writing changes too (like *–ail / –aux* or *–al / –aux*, or *œil / yeux*, *ciel / cieux*). *Œuf* is very peculiar, only the pronunciation changes significantly (just like you described). And *bœuf* happens to behave similarly.

A very few other words might have this strange feature. Until now, only *un os* `/ɔs/` whose plural is *des os* `/o/` came to mind.

Comment: Yes, indeed, *os* belongs to the list. And for the historical explanation see the [Banque de dépannage linguistique du Québec](http://66.46.185.79/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3067)

Comment: When the s is pronounced in the singular form, it is never pronounced in the plural form : un os `/ɔs/` , des os `/o/` ; un ours `/uRs/` des ours `/uR/` (more surprising for many people)

Comment: @rds: bien vu pour *ours* (je ne savais pas et je pense ne pas être le seul). Par contre permets moi de douter de la généralité de la règle que tu énonces… *vis*, *cactus* (et autres mots latins avec pluriel francisé), *vasistas* (qui a certes une [étymologie](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vasistas) douteuse), etc…

Comment: En effet, la règle n'est pas générale, et je pense aussi qu'en français moderne, on admet des ours `/uRs/` sans problème

Comment: Le pluriel de _ail_ s'écrit _aulx_. Oups pardon, je n'avais pas vu qu'il s'agissait de tous les mots se terminant par _...ail_.

Comment: What... On dit "des our" ?!

Answer (score 7):

On trouve un début d'explication en ce qui concerne la non prononciation du *F* final de mots se trouvant en premier élément de mots composés.

Dans sa *[Grammaire des grammaires](http://books.google.fr/books?id=DXg8AAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr#v=onepage&q&f=false)* (*Analyse raisonnée des meilleurs traités sur la langue française*) (1833)  Charles Pierre Girault-Duvivier cite le *Dictionnaire de l'Académie* (Paris, 1762) :

> la lettre F conserve presque toujours le son qui lui est propre au *commencement et au début des mots*.
>   *Finale*, elle se fait sentir au singulier comme au pluriel, aussi bien avant les mots qui commencent par une consonne qu'avant ceux qui commencent par une voyelle. [...]

et ensuite Levizac (*Grammaire philosophique et littéraire* − Paris 1801) :

> Il y a cependant quelques mots exceptés de cette règle. De ce nombre sont les mots *clef*, dont le F ne se prononce ni au singulier ni au pluriel ; *éteuf*, dont le F ne se prononce qu'en poésie ; *œuf frais*, *œuf dur*, *nerf-de-bœuf*, *cerf-volant*, *cerf-dix-cors*, *chef-d'œuvre*, *bœuf-gras*, *bœuf salé*, dont le F ne se prononce ni en prose, ni en poésie. **Cela est fondé sur ce que, si l'on faisait sentir la lettre F des premiers mots *œuf*, *cerf*, *nerf*, *chef*, *bœuf*, la prononciation serait lente, lorsqu'au contraire elle doit être prompte, chacun de ces mots étant intimement lié avec *frais*, *dur*, *bœuf*, *volant*, *dix-cors*,  *œuvre*, *gras*, *salé*, qui les accompagne.**

(C'est moi qui souligne.)

Comment: Et pour ceux, qui comme moi, ingoraient ce qu'est un *éteuf* : http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9teuf

Answer (score -2):

Notice the very slight differences in sound:

> oeil – yeux
>   jeu – jeux
>   oeuf – oeufs
>   ciel – cieux

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Your answer would be more helpful if you pointed out the differences you find interesting. Yes, these words have a variety of different sounds, so what are you referring to?

Comment: Some words take a different form when pluralized (*cheval*, *chevaux*), but I don't think that's related to the question.

Comment: how is jeu prononced differently than jeux?