# Unpredictable pronunciations

Tags: prononciation, orthographe

I know that French orthography is actually quite regular, in the sense that while there are numerous rules and certain exceptions, it's possible in the vast majority of cases to deduce the pronunciation reliably from the spelling.

However, there are certain classes of words where the pronunciation is not predictable: [œuf/œufs](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/pronunciation-of-oeuf-and-oeufs), and special pronunciations to facilitate disambiguation such as [tous](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1800/pronunciation-of-tous) and [plus](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/268/when-does-one-pronounce-the-s-in-plus). Or the fact that we write *ai* (from *avoir*) but say [e] even though usually the sequence *ai* represents [ɛ], or that *eurent* is pronounced [yʁ] even though *eu* is usually [ø].

I've been trying to find out other classes of French words whose pronunciation is not predictable from the orthography, but I've turned up nothing but information about irregular verbs.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Are you looking for pronunciation rules? For a list of exceptions?

Comment: I know the pronunciation rules (the regular component of French orthography); I'm interested in the irregular component. An example of the kind of systematic irregularity I'm after would be: "*the forms of avoir which have <eu> are pronounced [y], not [ø]*".

Comment: The very concepts of *irregularity rules* or *systematic irregularity* seem almost self-contradictory, even if I sort of understand what you've hoped to find. Collections of exceptions are however the only resource you'll have, I'm afraid.

Comment: The thing is, there can be systematic rules behind irregularities. Consider the strong verbs in English with vowel alternations -- I can't know *a priori* that *to run* is in the class and *to gun* isn't, but I know that within the class there are systematic rules. That's all I mean, and I did hesitate to write the words "systematic irregularity".

Answer (score 8):

I did end up finding what I wanted, in an 1858 book: [Eugène's key to the French pronunciation](http://tinyurl.com/7woxeyg).

Comment: Interesting to see that the pronunciation has not changed by much since then. Though, a few of the exceptions mentioned are not exceptions anymore.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Ah, interesting. What's an example?

Comment: For example *g* is not pronounced `/k/` in *gangrène* anymore; *legs* is (almost) always pronounced `/lɛɡ/`; no exception in *signet*, `/si.ɲɛ/`; *poignant* `/pwa.ɲɑ̃/`, *poignet* `/pwa.ɲɛ/`, *poignard* `/pwa.ɲaʁ/` are more common; the final *l* is voiced in *baril*, *chenil*, *gril*, *nombril*, *persil*, *sourcil*; both `/ɔ.si.le/` or `/ɔ.si.je/` are acceptable for *osciller*, *pupille* is commonly pronounced `/py.pij/`, titiller `/ti.ti.je/`, *vasciller* `/va.si.je/` or `/va.si.le/`; *cept* is now written *cep* and the *p* is voiced; *équitation* `/e.ki.ta.sjɔ̃/` has nothing special…

Comment: (For the last one, maybe you could still hear it pronounced as `/e.kɥi.ta.sjɔ̃/` sometimes, with the same sound as in *huit* `/ɥit/`, but who cares…) Last, *t* is not voiced anymore at the end of *aspect*, *circonspect*, *gratuit*, *respect*, *subit*. Oh, and there is of course a bunch of words in this text that have become obsolete.

Comment: Great find, thanks! @StéphaneGimenez, "the final l is voiced in [...] persil", seems like it depends on the region: https://francaisdenosregions.com/tag/persil/