# Pronunciation of plurals?

Tags: prononciation, pluriel

What is the difference in pronunciation between

> le livre rouge

and--

> les livres rouges

?

Comment: Non pour les noms et adjectifs ; les *s* finals sont muets

Comment: "Le" is pronounced like "duh" with an L instead of a D. "Les" is pronounces like "way" with an L instead of a W. *Rouge* and *rouges* are pronounced the same-- the *s* at the end is normally silent and has no effect on pronunciation.

Comment: @Aerovistae your description of "le" is not correct. I would not be able to describe in terms of English syllables however. "Les" pronounced "way" with an L would have a French (France) sound. The 'e' can be pronounced as the 'e' in 'Pelt'. This is what is used in Canada.

Comment: Sounds correct to an American ear. Close enough, anyway. I mean if OP encounters ANY French audio they're immediately going to figure it out, so...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, only the distinction between articles *le* (pronounced `/lə/`) and *les* (pronounced `/le/` or `/lɛ/`) marks the difference.

In most cases, the added *s* does not change the pronunciation, but sometimes a liaison between an adjective and the noun may change:

> un grand espace `/œ̃.ɡʁɑ̃.(t‿)ɛs.pas/`
> de grands espaces `/də.gʁɑ̃.z‿ɛs.pas/`
>
> la grande ère glacière `/la.ɡʁɑ̃.d‿ɛʁ.ɡla.sjɛʁ/`
> les grandes ères glacières `/le.ɡʁɑ̃d(ə).z‿ɛʁ.ɡla.sjɛʁ/`

And as always, [the occasional exceptions](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/pronunciation-of-%c5%93uf-and-%c5%93ufs).