# Pronunciation of "œuf" in "deux œufs kinder" and "bœuf "in "deux bœufs bourguignons" as an exception to silent /f/ in the plural

Tags: prononciation, pluriel

Say you wanted to buy some Kinder eggs in a store and had to ask for them and say :

*Je vais vous prendre deux œufs kinder.*

What would you actually say?

/døz**ø**kindɛr/

or

/døz**œf**kindɛr/.

Likewise, if on two consecutive Sundays you had eaten two bœufs bourguignons, once at your in-laws' and once at your parents'.  Would you say

/ʒɛmɑ̃ʒedø**bø**burgiɲɔ̃/

or

/ʒɛmɑ̃ʒedø**bœf**burgiɲɔ̃/?

I think I would sound the /f/ in both cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pronunciation of “œuf” and “œufs”](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/pronunciation-of-%c5%93uf-and-%c5%93ufs)

Comment: Hi, I'm aware of the question you're referring to.  I still think this little oddity, if confirmed, might deserve a separate enquiry.

Comment: Of course everybody would understand if you sound the /f/, but the usual pronunciation is  [døzøkindər]. Whether you want *deux œufs à la coque* or *deux œufs Kinder*  the pronunciation of *oeufs* ([ø]) is the same and there's no oddity about it. The only oddity is the fact that the /f/ is not usually sounded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm asking because as a native speaker of French, I would sound the /f/ in this particular instance and I would like to know if that pronunciation is shared by anyone else if at all.

Comment: Dans ce cas je pense que ta question est probablement mal formulée, même après que l'aies modifiée. Je pense que ce serait le genre de question « référendum » qui sont souvent qualifiées de *primarily opinion based*. Voir la [FAQ](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where [...] there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”

Comment: Merci, ce n'est pas tant une question de "I'm curious if people feel like I do" que "I'm curious if people say as I do".  Le problème de prononciation que je soulève se pose également pour bœuf, mettons que vous mangiez un bœuf bourguignon ce dimanche, que vous en ayez mangé un dimanche dernier, vous auriez mangé deux bœufs bourguignons, alors, /døbøburgiɲɔ̃/ ou /døbœfburgiɲɔ̃/?  Bon appétit!

Comment: Et de même « des os à moelle », est-ce qu'on prononce ça comme « des os à ronger » ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Effectivement, j'ai aussi tendance à ne pas appliquer la prononciation normale du pluriel de « des bœufs bourguignons » lorsque'il s'agit de la locution : je mange [de.**bœf**.bur.gi.ɲɔ̃] le dimanche alors que je vois [de.bø.bur.gi.ɲɔ̃] dans un pré. De même pour « des œufs Kinder » [de.**zœf**.kin.dɛʁ] ne sont pas « des œufs durs » [de.**zø**.dyʁ], « des os à moelle » [de.**zɔ.s**a.mwal] (ou [de.**zɔs‿**a.mwal] ?) mais « des os à ronger » [de.**zo**.a.ʁɔ̃.ʒe].

Il y a quelques expressions figées dans lesquelles une prononciation figée est documentée. La [BDL Québécoise](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3067) cite par exemple « bœuf gras » [bø.gʁa], « paquet d'os » [pa.ke.dɔs], « en chair et en os » [ɑ̃.ʃɛʁ.e.ɑ̃.ɔs]. [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/boeuf) cite aussi « bœuf salé » [bø.sa.le]. (Il y a aussi des variations régionales et individuelles, je ne rentre pas là dedans.) Je ne trouve pas de référence pour « bœufs bourguignons » et « os à moelle ». Cela n'expliquerait pas pourquoi « œufs Kinder » serait prononcé différemment.

Pour « œufs Kinder », le fait que « Kinder » n'a pas une sonorité française (la première syllabe se termine par [n], et la succession de sons [ind] est impossible en français) influe sans doute à adopter une prononciation plus « lettre par lettre » comme on le fait pour des mots étrangers : on prononce donc plus volontiers le « f ». Je doute cependant que ce phénomène soit déterminant.

Ces expressions ont en commun que le mot dont la prononciation change au pluriel est au milieu d'une expression idiomatique, qui est par certains côtés perçue comme un seul mot. Or en français la marque du pluriel se trouve toujours à la fin du mot. C'est plus flagrant (et mieux documenté) lorsque la prononciation et l'orthographe changent tous les deux au pluriel. Par exemple « un [œil-de-bœuf](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C5%93il-de-b%C5%93uf) », « des œils-de-bœuf » [œj.də.bœf] ; « un [œil-de-chat](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C5%93il-de-chat) », « des œils-de-chat » [œj.də.ʃa] (mais « des yeux de lynx », l'expression n'est pas assez figée). Je pense que c'est cela qui explique qu'il se forme de nouvelles exceptions où l'on prononce un pluriel comme le singulier.

Comment: Peut-être aussi l'idée que les voyelles fermées en position finale s'ouvrent « dans bien des cas » si elles finissent par être suivies d'une consonne, comme avec les noms/adjectifs (sot, berger) prenant la forme au féminin et les verbes conjugués (je peux/ils peuvent). Je dis ça simplement parce que dans ce genre de cas LBU14§26 dit « et inversement » et donne _oeuf_. Peut-être que le k et le b, c'est la goûte qui fait déborder le vase et ramène l'oeuf dans le giron du « dans bien des cas » ?

Answer (score 0):

Comme parfois il est bon aussi de réellement l'entendre :

[Petite vidéo pour les sons œufs, et bœufs](https://youtu.be/ueyLAvkoZnc)